# GetInches of Screen Size

Tags: vb.net, wmi, screen-size

I currently run this

```
Private Sub GetInches()
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
                "\root\WMI", _
                "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams")
    For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()

        Dim width As Double = CByte(queryObj("MaxHorizontalImageSize")) / 2.54
        Dim height As Double = CByte(queryObj("MaxVerticalImageSize")) / 2.54
        Dim diagonal As Double = Decimal.Round(Math.Sqrt(width * width + height * height), 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
        tbVGARES.Text = diagonal
    Next



    searcher.Dispose()
End Sub
```

But when I run it on a few laptops the inches are off sometimes.

1 screen shows 15.5" while screen is 15.6"
Other screen shows 14" while screen is 13.7"
etc.

Maybe somebody knows a way to solve this?
The standard sizes of lcd screens on laptops are:

> 10,1" 11,6" 12,0"12,1"13" 13,3" 14" 14,1" 15" 15,4" 15,6" 16" 16,4" 17,1" 17,3" 18,4"

Comment: The query returns integers with a unit of centimeters.  So of course it can never be more accurate than +/- 0.5 cm.  You want more accuracy, clearly you have no use for this query.

Comment: I see, i have to try something else then.  But i am lost in idea's. I don't have that much knowledge on how to solve this.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks for that Hans ;) I have tried the post below from Matt Wilko, doesn't solve the problem. 

My program is to show all information on a laptop, export it to csv file. And this is used for selling laptops etc. So this solution should show the right size of the screen. I hope this makes it more clearer why i need the right size.

So how could i get a more precise size ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work:

```
    For Each scr In Screen.AllScreens
        Dim width = scr.Bounds.Width / Me.CreateGraphics.DpiX
        Dim height = scr.Bounds.Height / Me.CreateGraphics.DpiY
        Dim size = Math.Sqrt((width * width) + (height * height))
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Screen {0} is Size {1:0.00} inches", scr.DeviceName, size))
    Next
```

Comment: This shows on my Lenovo G580 16.3" instead of 15.6"
Doesn't this use DPI?